# Is it possible to format code in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, code-formatting

Is there a means to **format code snippets** in any way, ideally a Markdown like syntax, in Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online)?

Using italics just doesn't sit right with me.

[image: Formatting code in Visual Studio Team Services]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found this extension from the feature request [@eddie linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37825137/80428).

## [Markdown](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschleiden.markdown)

> Markdown is a custom work item form control, that allows you to edit the rich text fields on your work items with a Markdown enabled editor.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can copy/paste formatted code from a html view. For example Google docs with the "Code pretty" AddOn or an online tool like http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/
This way you can also change font size, family and color if you need. It looks like [image]

Comment: This is extremely inconvenient because the information pasted *within* might not make sense in the context of VSTS, resulting in weird looking comments and code.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to achieve this feature. And there is already a feature request submitted for this on VSTS User Voice. You can vote it up here: [Support markdown as an alternative to html for workitems](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/7145974-support-markdown-as-an-alternative-to-html-for-wor).

Comment: So did nobody think "hey, people might want to include code snippets when creating Work Items in VSTS"? Lack of support for this makes the entire product a joke in my eyes.